# How to open another page after rewarded ad is watched in java?

Tags: java, android-studio, admob

```
 MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {

                loadRewardAd();
            }
        });
      }

private void loadRewardAd() {
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        RewardedAd.load(this, "ca-app-pub-7826872218727678/2709094630",
                adRequest, new RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(@NonNull LoadAdError loadAdError) {
                        // Handle the error.
                        Log.d(TAG, loadAdError.getMessage());
                        mRewardedAd = null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(@NonNull RewardedAd rewardedAd) {
                        mRewardedAd = rewardedAd;
                        Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.");

                        mRewardedAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when ad is shown.
                                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was shown.");
                                mRewardedAd = null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                                // Called when ad fails to show.
                                Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                                // Called when ad is dismissed.
                                // Set the ad reference to null so you don't show the ad a second time.
                                Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.");
                                loadRewardAd();
                            }
                        });
                    }


                });


    }
 private void showRewardad() {

        if (mRewardedAd != null) {
            mRewardedAd.show(this, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                @Override
                public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
                    // Handle the reward.
                    Log.d(TAG, "The user earned the reward.");
                    int rewardAmount = rewardItem.getAmount();
                    String rewardType = rewardItem.getType();
                }
            });
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can launch your another screen in onUserEarnedReward.

```
 mRewardedAd.show(this, new OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
        @Override
        public void onUserEarnedReward(@NonNull RewardItem rewardItem) {
           //After handling reward, Launch your new screen from here

        }
    });
```